# How to resolve reference for multiple objects

Tags: go, kubernetes, kubernetes-go-client

I am using the go-client library.
I am searching for mounted secrets inside the workload.
In my example we have two workloads: `daemonset` and `deployments`.
Although both of them are different objects, they have similar structure:

```
type DaemonSet struct {
    metav1.TypeMeta `json:",inline"`
    metav1.ObjectMeta `json:"metadata,omitempty" protobuf:"bytes,1,opt,name=metadata"`
    Spec DaemonSetSpec `json:"spec,omitempty" protobuf:"bytes,2,opt,name=spec"`
    Status DaemonSetStatus `json:"status,omitempty" protobuf:"bytes,3,opt,name=status"`
}


type Deployment struct {
    metav1.TypeMeta `json:",inline"`
    metav1.ObjectMeta `json:"metadata,omitempty" protobuf:"bytes,1,opt,name=metadata"`
    Spec DeploymentSpec `json:"spec,omitempty" protobuf:"bytes,2,opt,name=spec"`
    Status DeploymentStatus `json:"status,omitempty" protobuf:"bytes,3,opt,name=status"`
}
```

I am getting errors of:

> Unresolved reference

This happens because the compilation doesn't know what object I am referring to: `v1beta2.DaemonSetList` or `v1beta2.DeploymentList`.

How can I resolve it for both of them ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no. This happens because your variable `controllerList` is not declared in the right scope.

it must be declared in the common scope shared by both the `for` loop and the `switch` statement, the parent scope, IE the `if controllerName != ...`.

** Note that to post on SO you must NOT include screenshot of the code, but provide a minimal reproducible example of the code, copy && pasted && linted in your post.

Comment: The problem is that I cannot place the `controllerList` shared scope because I am casting in each `case` the appropriate object.

Comment: make `controllerList` a slice of type `[]interface{}` and deal with it

Comment: I used `var controllerList []interface{}` and `var workloadItems interface{}` right after the firs `for` loop. It now recognize the `workloadItems`.